# i have a jQuery carousel / slider which needs counter slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angular, jquery-ui

[Updated Demo :](http://codepen.io/syedazam/pen/Opqogm) 
Any help is greatly appreciated !!

i have developed a carousel / slider with vertical thumbnails which is working perfectly fine, but i have a extra requirement that number of slides count has to be shown, whenever the user scrolls next set of count has to be updated. 
just like yahoo.com slider (https://www.yahoo.com/news/)  with up & down arrows.

html :

```
 <div id="featured">

      <!-- First Content -->
      <div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
             <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="">
             <div class="info">
                <h2><a href="#">15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</a></h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tincidunt condimentum lacus. Pellentesque ut diam....<a href="#">read more</a></p>
             </div>
         </a>
      </div>

      <!-- Second Content -->
      <div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="info">
            <h2><a href="#">20 Beautiful Long Exposure Photographs</a></h2>
            <p>Vestibulum leo quam, accumsan nec porttitor a, euismod ac tortor. Sed ipsum lorem, sagittis non egestas id, suscipit....<a href="#">read more</a></p>
         </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- Third Content -->
      <div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="info">
            <h2><a href="#">35 Amazing Logo Designs</a></h2>
            <p>liquam erat volutpat. Proin id volutpat nisi. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur facilisis sollicitudin ornare....<a href="#">read more</a></p>
         </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Fourth Content -->
      <div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="info">
            <h2><a href="#">Create Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</a></h2>
            <p>Quisque sed orci ut lacus viverra interdum ornare sed est. Donec porta, erat eu pretium luctus, leo augue sodales....<a href="#">11read more</a></p>
         </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!-- 5 Content -->
      <div id="fragment-5" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="info">
            <h2><a href="#">Create Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</a></h2>
            <p>Quisque sed orci ut lacus viverra interdum ornare sed est. Donec porta, erat eu pretium luctus, leo augue sodales....<a href="#">11read more</a></p>
         </div>
         </a>
      </div>

       <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-1">
                <a class="nav-bg-full" href="#fragment-1">
                    <div class="img-bg hide-for-small" style="background:url('images/image1-small.jpg') no-repeat; width:100%; background-size: 100%; position:relative">
                        <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="show-for-small">
                        <div class="mob-img">
                            <img src="images/image1-small.jpg" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
                    </div>

                </a>

            </li>

            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-2">
                <a class="nav-bg-full" href="#fragment-2">              
                <div class="img-bg hide-for-small" style="background:url('images/image2-small.jpg') no-repeat; width:100%; background-size: 100%; position:relative">
                        <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
                </div>


                <div class="show-for-small">
                    <div class="mob-img">
                        <img src="images/image2-small.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
                </div>

                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-3">
                <a class="nav-bg-full" href="#fragment-3">
                    <div class="img-bg hide-for-small" style="background:url('images/image3-small.jpg') no-repeat; width:100%; background-size: 100%; position:relative">
                        <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="show-for-small">
                        <div class="mob-img">
                            <img src="images/image3-small.jpg" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </li>


            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-4">
                <a class="nav-bg-full" href="#fragment-4">

                    <div class="img-bg hide-for-small" style="background:url('images/image4-small.jpg') no-repeat; width:100%; background-size: 100%; position:relative">
                        <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="show-for-small">
                        <div class="mob-img">
                            <img src="images/image4-small.jpg" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
                    </div>

                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-5">
                <a class="nav-bg-full" href="#fragment-5">

                    <div class="img-bg hide-for-small" style="background:url('images/image1-small.jpg') no-repeat; width:100%; background-size: 100%; position:relative">
                        <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="show-for-small">
                        <div class="mob-img">
                            <img src="images/image4-small.jpg" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
                    </div>

                </a>
                </li>

        </ul>
        <div class="slide-counter">
            <span class="s-counter">1-4 of 20</span>
            <span class="s-arrow">
                <div class="up-arrow">Scroll up</div>
                <div class="down-arrow">Scroll down</div>
            </span>
        </div>

   </div>
```

css :

```
#featured {
    width: 920px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 400px;
    background: #fff;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav li {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
}
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav li img {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 5px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav li span {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color:#fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0 );
    width: 93%;
}
#featured li.ui-tabs-nav-item a {
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#featured li.ui-tabs-nav-item a:hover {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
#featured li.ui-tabs-selected {
    background: url('images/selected-item.gif') top left no-repeat;
}
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a {
    background: #ccc;
}
#featured .ui-tabs-panel {
    width: 620px;
    /*height: 250px;*/
    background: #999;
    position: relative;
}
#featured .ui-tabs-panel img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#featured .ui-tabs-panel .info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0 );
    width:620px;
}
#featured .info h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#featured .info p {
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #f0f0f0;
}
#featured .info a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: arial;
}
#featured .info a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#featured .ui-tabs-hide {
    display: none;
}
.ui-tabs-nav::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.ui-tabs-nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.ui-tabs-nav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #000000;
}
.show-for-small {
    display:none !important;
}
.img-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}


/*slider count starts*/
.slide-counter {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 280px;
    background: #f00;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
.s-arrow {
    float:right;
}
.up-arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.down-arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*slider count ends*/


@media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width:760px) {
    #featured {
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    #featured .ui-tabs-panel {
        width:300px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    #featured ul.ui-tabs-nav {
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    #featured .ui-tabs-panel .info {
        width:auto;
    }
    #featured li.ui-tabs-nav-item a {
        height:auto;
        background:#004990;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
    #featured .info a {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .hide-for-small {
        display:none !important;
    }
    .show-for-small {
        display:block !important;
    }
    .mob-img {
        float:left;
        width:100px;
    }
    #featured ul.ui-tabs-nav li span {
        position: relative;
        background: none;
        float: left;
        width: 170px;
    }
}
```

JS :

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}})//.tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
var sliderNavLength = $('.ui-tabs-nav li').length;

$('.slide-counter').find('.s-counter').text("1 - " + sliderNavLength);

alert(" sliderNavLength - " + sliderNavLength);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have made it.. 
here's the **[demo](http://codepen.io/syedazam/pen/vxMpgE)**

[DEMO with disabled Arrow keys](http://codepen.io/syedazam/pen/dvxZdR)

js :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle", duration: "fast"}});

        var sliderNavLength = $('.ui-tabs-nav li').length;
        var sliderNavUlHeight = $(".ui-tabs-nav")[0].scrollHeight;

        var sliderNavLiHeight = 0;

        $(".ui-tabs-nav li:lt(3)").each(function() {
           sliderNavLiHeight += $(this).height();
        });
        var recCount = 3;

        $('.ui-tabs-nav li:first-child()').addClass('firstChild');
        $('.ui-tabs-nav li:last-child()').addClass('lastChild');

        $('.slide-counter').find('.s-counter').text(" of " + sliderNavLength);      

        $('.up-arrow').click(function(e){            

             if (recCount > 3) {

                 var sliderScrollCountMinus = $('.ui-tabs-nav').scrollTop() - sliderNavLiHeight;
                 $('.ui-tabs-nav').animate({ scrollTop: sliderScrollCountMinus }, 1000);
                 $('.counter').val( parseInt($('.counter').val()) - 3 );
                 $('.counterSingle').val( parseInt($('.counterSingle').val()) - 3 );

                 recCount = recCount - 3;
             }

        });

        $('.down-arrow').click(function(e){         
            if (sliderNavLength > recCount) {
                var sliderScrollCountPlus = $('.ui-tabs-nav').scrollTop() + sliderNavLiHeight;
                $('.ui-tabs-nav').animate({ scrollTop: sliderScrollCountPlus }, 1000);

                $('.counter').val( parseInt($('.counter').val()) + 3 );
                $('.counterSingle').val( parseInt($('.counterSingle').val()) + 3 );

                recCount = recCount + 3;            
            }           
        });

      });
```